# Complex integral $\int_{C(0,2)}\frac{e^z}{z^3+z}$dz

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Im struggling a bit with the follow complex integral:

$\int_{C(0,2)}\frac{e^z}{z^3+z}$dz

My solution so far:

1. $\int_{C(0,2)}\frac{e^z}{z^3+z}$dz = $\int_{C(0,2)}\frac{e^z}{z(z-i)(z+i)}$dz where all the singularities are within $C$ $\Rightarrow$

   $\int_{C(0,2)}\frac{e^z}{z^3+z}$dz $=2\pi i * (Res(0)+Res(i)+Res(-i))$
2. Calculating residues

   $Res(0)=lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=lim_{z\rightarrow 0}(z-0)\frac{e^z}{z(z-i)(z+i)} = 1$

   $Res(i)=lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=lim_{z\rightarrow i}(z-i)\frac{e^z}{z(z-i)(z+i)} = \frac{e^i}{-2}$

   $Res(i)=lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)=lim_{z\rightarrow -i}(z+i)\frac{e^z}{z(z-i)(z+i)} = \frac{e^{-i}}{2}$

Which gets me $\int_{C(0,2)}\frac{e^z}{z(z-i)(z+i)}$dz = $2 \pi i * (1+\frac{e^i}{-2} + \frac{e^{-i}}{2})$

While the book says it should be $2 \pi i * (1+\cos(1))$

Is this the same answer, or does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I agree with you; I think the book's $+$ sign is a misprint.

Comment: Your residue at $z=-i$ is missing a sign. And as J.G. already mentioned, the result should be $2\pi i (1-\cos 1)$.